# imeOptions not working in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-softkeyboard

I am using `imeOptions` and they are just working fine. However, I have an `ExpandableListView` and one of the childs is a layout with 3 `EditText` and `imeOptions` are not even displaying for those.

Any idea on what could be the problem? Did anyone use `imeOptions` in a normal `ListView` (ie is this a limitation for `ListView`s in general or just for `ExpandableListView`)?

UPDATE: I just did a test with a standard `ListView` instead of the expandable one and I face the same problem.

This is the list item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <View 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="73"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:id="@+id/settingsText1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/settingsText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:hint="OLD PASSWORD"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield2" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:id="@+id/settingsText2"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/settingsText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:hint="NEW PASSWORD"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield2" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:id="@+id/settingsText3"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:hint="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
            android:background="@drawable/textfield2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="27" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As in your case, most of my textviews with imeOptions were working, but I had one that was an AutoCompleteTextView in a DialogFragment that wasn't showing up.  I added the inputType from the answer below and voila, it's there!

Answer (score 4):

It was not a `ListView` problem after all, but a rather strange constrain. `imeOptions` are not showing if there is not `inputType` parameter present

So this will work

```
<EditText
  android:inputType="textPassword"
  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/settingsText2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

while this won't

```
<EditText
  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/settingsText2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```